# Is there a limit in the number of blocks that can be randomized in Qualtrics?

Tags: limits, qualtrics

does anyone know whether:
1) there is a limit in the number of blocks that can be added in a survey in Qualtrics?
2) is there a limit in the number of blocks that can be included in the Randomizer in Qualtrics?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there are no limits to either of the above.